# ¿Cómo evitar venganzas a la hora de votar posts?

Tags: discusión, respuestas, reputación

Lo siguiente me ha pasado en varias comunidades y lo considero bastante injusto. 
A veces, veo una pregunta de la cual conozco la respuesta, y sé que la respuesta no es tan sencilla como parece. Entonces me gusta intervenir con una respuesta. Sin embargo, me gusta leer las respuestas que ya se han dado. En muchos casos, veo que hay una respuesta, aparentemente buena, pero con algo que hace que la pregunta no sea tan sencilla.

Ej: (puedo buscar el post si queréis), pregunta sobre como distinguir entre complementos directo e indirecto. Aparentemente sencilla pero no, porque también el usuario dice que lo entendía hasta que leyó sobre leísmos y laísmos. Hay varias respuestas, una de ellas se limita a decir que le es indirecto y lo/la es directo. Respuesta válida, pero si tenemos en cuenta que el usuario pregunta también por leísmos y laísmos no lo es. Le doy un negativo a la respuesta y a modo de mejorar, le dejo un comentario diciendo por qué considero que su respuesta no es válida y respondo yo. Resultado, el usuario al que le he dado el negativo me da un negativo.

En fin, ¿qué hacemos con estos comportamientos? me parece injusto dar un negativo por 'me has dado un negativo', y el usuario a fecha de hoy no ha mejorado su respuesta.

Comment: Tarde o temprano todos recibimos no solo un negativo, sino un negativo que consideramos injusto. Es parte (inevitable) del proceso de participar en los stacks, q tienen este sistema para que la comunidad respalde el contenido de cada post. Como veterano puedo decirte que sé que esto es muy molesto cuando empiezas y estás trabajando mucho para aportar contenido de calidad y alcanzar tus metas (privilegios, medallas, niveles de rep, etc.), pero como otras cosas frustrantes que tiene la vida aprendes a ignorarlo y a centrarte en lo que tú realmente quieres hacer: aportar contenido de calidad.

Comment: Posteas un enlace, por favorcito?

Comment: Mira este ejemplo.  Yo posteo mi propia manera de ver o explicar las cosas así: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32708/9385.  Quizás te sirva también.  A veces recibo votos por mis respuestas suplementarias o alternativas, a veces no, pero me da la satisfacción saber que presenté un punto de vista un poco diferente. // Por otra parte me gusta aprender de los demas aqui.  Muchas veces las cosas son mas complicadas de lo que creia.

Answer (score 6):

Personalmente no creo que los negativos por venganza sean la respuesta a nada. Dicho esto, a la pregunta de *¿qué hacemos?*, así en general, no sé qué decirte, porque los votos son privados y ni siquera los moderadores podemos saber quién votó positivo o negativo a una respuesta. Podría haber métodos indirectos pero nunca podríamos estar completamente seguros.

He visto, en todo caso, que esta pregunta [ya fue planteada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106704/350184) al principio de los tiempos en Meta, y las respuestas que se obtuvieron fueron:

- Añadir un aviso en tu perfil de usuario, explicando tu tendencia a votar negativo ante respuestas incompletas o mejorables, y que quitas los negativos si la respuesta se mejora o se demuestra que tu negativo no tenía fundamento.
- Aceptarlo. Los negativos por venganza son parte de un sistema que no es perfecto, y tampoco son algo muy grave para tu reputación, ya que puedes aguantar cinco negativos por cada positivo que te den. Peor sería que te votaran negativo en serie, pero el sistema sí tiene medidas de seguridad contra eso.

Por último, comentar que del mismo modo que no podemos estar 100% seguros de que el negativo venga del usuario al que votaste negativo, dado que pudo ser casualidad y provenir de otro usuario, tampoco podemos estar seguro de que fuera por venganza, pudo ser que esa persona tenga tus mismos criterios de voto, solo que no dejó comentario. Así que otra cosa que puedes hacer es dejar un comentario pidiendo explicaciones por el negativo, para que puedas mejorar tus posts.

---

En otro orden de cosas, me gustaría pedir a la comunidad que no ejerza sus votos negativos por despecho. Dejar un comentario ante un negativo no es algo habitual, ya que el votante está descubriéndose y por tanto requiere valentía. **No respondamos ante la valentía con venganza.** Aprovechemos la ocasión para aprender, que es para lo que estamos aquí, y mejoremos los posts si es posible, o rebatamos con lógica el negativo.

Comment: he leído tu respuesta y me surge otra pregunta, pero ya es otra discusión sobre negativos sin comentarios para poder mejorar la situación

Comment: @Iria como nota aparte, me gustaría comentar que yo los votos negativos los reservo para cuando una respuesta va en la dirección totalmente opuesta a la deseada. Si una respuesta va por buen camino pero es mejorable, no la castigo con un negativo sino que le dejo un comentario positivo invitando al tiempo a su mejora. Creo que así se consigue una mejor respuesta por parte del usuario. Pero en todo caso, esto ya es criterio personal de cada uno, y no creo que haya algún criterio que sea mejor que otro. Solo distintos enfoques.

Comment: entiendo tu postura @Charlie, pero si el autor de la pregunta dice claramente que ha leído sobre laísmo y leísmo y que le confunde, una respuesta tan tajante... es no haber leídio la pregunta e ir en la dirección opuesta, por no tenerlo en cuenta. Yo los negativos los doy en los siguientes casos: 1.- respuesta  no es correcta y se induce a pensar que no ha entendido la pregunta o no se la ha leído. 2.- respuesta no aporta nada, es una versión de otra respuesta y solo se ha publicado para obtener popularidad, y en este caso no suelo penalizarlas, directamente no puntúo